# Cannot start or initialize IBM WebSphere

Tags: websphere

I am unable to start or initialize IBM WebSphere. I have a clean install of Linux CentOS. I have installed IBMs Installation Manager. In IBMs Installation Manager, I have added repository `http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V85WASDeveloperILAN/repository.config`, and I was then able to successfully install IBM WebSphere Application Server for Developers, version 8.5.5.11.

[image]

Next I have created a profile named AppSrv01. In the firststeps console, I select Installation verification.

[image]

The log file displays the following. If I Start the server, the same messages are displayed. I am not sure why the initialization displays errors, and whey the server cannot start, on a clean install.

```
Start running the following command:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/startServer.sh server1 -profileName AppSrv01
>runConfigActions script execution failed. Exit code: 1
>Exception caught while waiting for runConfigActions script to complete: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/runConfigActions.h
```

Answer (score 2):

First check the permissions and ownership within the WebSphere's filesystem. If WebSphere is normally started under a non-root user, perform recursive change as root user following this example:

```
chown -R [wasadm:wasadm] /opt/IBM/WebSphere
chmod -R 777 /opt/IBM/WebSphere
```

or try to start jvm as root user or super user. If this doesn't help, 
clean the WebSphere temporary cache to free up space. Remove the files and folders in the following sub-directories:

```
[profile_root]=> /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01

    [profile_root]/temp/

    [profile_root]/wstemp/

    [profile_root]/config/temp/
```

Try the following workaround:

Create the file: `runConfigActions.disableAtServerStartup` under the `[profile_root]/properties/service/` directory.

Try to startup the failing jvm again.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case others run into the same problem, I want to share the fix for my environment. DNS was unable to resolve the WebSphere hostname to the WebSphere IP address. Configuring the DNS server to resolve the WebSphere hostname to the WebSphere IP address fixed the issue.